# Angularjs: is this the correct way to use controller and directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Normally the directive will use data in the scope, for example:

```
<div my-directive 
     data-x='x' 
     data-y='y'
     data-z='z'
     ...>
</div>
```

However, the arguments of the directive grow very fast. So I put them in a model class.
So each of my directive has it's own model class.

```
<div my-directive 
     data-model='myDirectiveModel'>
</div>
```

In controllers, I just need to set

```
$scope.myDirectiveModel = { 
    x: 100.
    y: 200,
    add: function(){
       return this.x + this.y;
    }
};
```

Is this the correct way to use controller and directive?

Comment: Perhaps it is quite subjective... Anyway, I have used this pattern to solve this kind of problems, so I would be OK with it.

Comment: It's common for coding conventions to contain a maximum number of arguments for functions until a config object is used. It may be that you want your three most important arguments explicit, and others implicit within a config object. I agree this is subjective however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly a cleaner way of passing data through to a directive than having lots attributes in the markup.

However I would suggest that one of the good things about Angular is it's declarative syntax. If you always and exclusively do what you've suggested, when you come to read back your markup in a couple of months you'll have to delve into code to see what's going on. Being more explicit in your markup could save you some time. For example when you do this:

```
<div my-directive show-chickens="yes" chimp-count="monkeys" />
```

less is hidden from you when you read the markup.

However, if you are happy with your approach and want to continue, I would just declare the model as the value of the directive attribute like so...

```
<div my-directive='myDirectiveModel' />
```

just to make it even more clean.

Comment: No problem, anytime ;)